# How can I use ScreenCaptureKit to capture an entire desktop?

Tags: macos, screencapturekit

There appears to be a limitation or bug in ScreenCaptureKit where it cannot simply capture a desktop. However, many applications do this, so it must be possible. Using the [the official Apple sample application](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/capturing_screen_content_in_macos) exhibits this bug.

Here's the code in question:

```swift
            guard let display = selectedDisplay else { fatalError("No display selected.") }
            var excludedApps = [SCRunningApplication]()
            // If a user chooses to exclude the app from the stream,
            // exclude it by matching its bundle identifier.
            if isAppExcluded {
                excludedApps = availableApps.filter { app in
                    Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier == app.bundleIdentifier
                }
            }
            // Create a content filter with excluded apps.
            filter = SCContentFilter(display: display,
                                     excludingApplications: excludedApps,
                                     exceptingWindows: [])
```

In the sample application, when the isAppExcluded is enabled, everything works fine. However, when you set this to false (there is a checkbox in the application), the stream immediately stops. If we recompile the application to start the stream with the variable set to false, the stream never starts. In both cases, toggling the variable to true fixes the stream and it works normally.

**Question:** How can I capture an entire display and all of its windows with ScreenCaptureKit?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. I think it's a bug in the ScreenCaptureKit API that prevents unfiltered calls (aka. without any app or window filter) from being processed correctly.

A possible workaround I've had success with is using the [`initWithDisplay:includingApplications:exceptingWindows:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/sccontentfilter/3919807-initwithdisplay?language=objc) initialization, passing all applications as input.

For more information and a complete snippet, see also: https://federicoterzi.com/blog/screencapturekit-failing-to-capture-the-entire-display